# What is the recommended and correct clean way for an Ignite client node to disconnect from an Ignite cluster?

Tags: ignite

I have been unable to find any prescribed way for an ignite client to cleanly pull out of a cluster. We have a long running process and we'd like it to join (some) cluster as needed and leave the cluster when it's done doing whatever it needed to do. We don't want to carry any local Ignite state between sessions.  Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Ignite.close()` or `Ignition.stop()`

Comment: K thanks. That wasn't working or us.  When I get back to it I'll get more details as to what was happening. Just to confirm after .close() or .stop() should the client be completely out? as in the grid should no longer include the client node in any nodes list at all? and should not try to talk to it? TY

Comment: Yes, should be completely gone, resources released and so on

Comment: From Ignite listserv. With this clarification I can accept the answer.

Just Ignition.stop(true);  should be enough to wait till checkpoint ends.  So it could be just one call to this method without anything else.

If you did a prior call to ignite.close() this is equal to Ignition.stop(false) and this cause Ignite node to stop without waiting for checkpoint to finish. In that case, further calls have no effect.

In any case, this warning says that it may require a longer time to restore memory during start-up, but not something that is dangerous for data.

Sincerely,
Dmitriy Pavlov